# How to stop overlapping in ViewPager when change the tab

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have two fragments one is simple video and another is event video,When i call onTabSelected multiple time in very short time period, means change tab quickly then my previous tab video's sound is continuously playing in second tab video background

```
 public void bindAllTab() {
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPagerAdapter = new AllVideoViewPager(fm);
    viewPagerAdapter = new AllVideoViewPager(fm);
    //  Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new AllVideoFrag(videoid, carListAsString, screen, pos), "All Video");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ContestVideoFrag(videoid, carListAsString, screen, pos), "Contest");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            //  new videoAdapter().pause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
}
```

please suggest how i can stop previous tab if user can move to second tab and vice versa. and this is my PageChangeListener.

```
 private final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {
        FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(currentPosition);
        fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();
        FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(newPosition);
        fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment();
        currentPosition = newPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```